# Converting a <ul> to textfields

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Im making a small plugin for wordpress and so far a user can select any post or page an drag the order of the pages just like this:
https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

The problem im facing now is how to save this list in that order to be able to display it front-end. Can i convert them to hidden textfields or something? How would one go about doing such a thing? I need it to be updated if someone changes the order of the list.

For example if the user has made his/her list like this:

1. -item1
2. -item2
3. -item3

it should display in that order on the webpage, if they later go and drag the items around and update the post/page to example:

1. -item2
2. -item3
3. -item1

The changes should be reflected on the front-end aswell. I got the drag'n'drop all working but dont know how to save the data from the list.

Can i loop trough the list somehow and save it via some hidden fields in my metabox perhaps?

kind regards,
Emil Carlsson

Clicking a button to open up the list of pages/posts:

```
    <button type="button" id="hl-link-wp-button">
                <span class="cms-page-link-icon cms-page-link-icon-link">&nbsp;</span> Länk
            </button>
```

that runs this jquery function:

```
$('#hl-link-wp-button').click(function (e) {
            wpActiveEditor = true;
            wpLink.open($(this).attr('id'));
            return false;
        });
```

now a user has selected a page/post and press submit this gets called:

```
 $('#wp-link-submit').click(function (event) {
            var linkAtts = wpLink.getAttrs();   
            $('#test').val(linkAtts.href); 
  $("#sortable").append("<li>" + theValue + "</li>");
```

the value now populate a textfield for testing purposes and allso appends to a list.

textfield:

```
    <input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="<?php echo relaterade_sidor_get_meta( 'test' ); ?>">
```

list:

```
<ul id="sortable">
```

if i start from point 1 i can add more items to the list but the textfield obviously can only hold one value. The list thats get created is what i wish to save.

adding a post/page link: http://gyazo.com/ee197791ddcdf48b42982e0bb641858b
after adding a few links i get a list (unstyled): http://gyazo.com/6c8fbde88ab3bf18c50f45ef4f4c5295

this is the list that i somehow wish to save and display frontend.

cheers

Comment: can you show what you have so far

Comment: really not enough known about use case for this sortable list. Also, there are several ways to serialize order data within the sortable docs

Comment: Is the order going to be saved on the server? Should it be clientside only save? You need details.

Comment: For generic reordering of "records", we wrote our own plugin, but the basic idea is to tell the server where the item is inserted using Ajax to send each change and storing PK values as `data-` attributes on the `LI`s. Best option we found was to send the id of the dragged item and the id of the element to insert it after (or null/undefined for the first position).

Comment: added some code and pictures to clearify.